# React, state, Why the `count` is not defined?

Tags: reactjs

When I  click the `Update', this error shows.

The error :

> `app.js?7ac9:18 Uncaught ReferenceError: count is not defined`

```
import  React, {Compoment} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
class Counter extends  React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            count: 0,
        };
    }
    handleClick(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        this.setState({
            count: count + 1,
        });
    }
    render () {
        return(
            <div>
                <p>{this.state.count}</p>
                <a href="#" onClick={this.handleClick}> Update</a>
            </div>
            );
    }
}
ReactDOM.render(<Counter />, document.getElementById('app'))
```

I have defined the count with `this.state` in the constructor. Do you write the good code in the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Following:

```
handleClick(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        this.setState({
            count: this.state.count + 1,
        });
    }
```